# Sequelize raw query not properly printed

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm attempting to construct a Sequelize query in Node.js, but encountering an issue with variable substitution. Below is the Sequelize query I've written:

```
var homePosts = db.postbox.findAll({
        where: {
            user_id: {
                $or: {
                    $eq: id,
                    $in: [id]
                }
            }
        },
        attributes: ["user_posts_id"],
        limit: 5
    });
    return homePosts;
```

However, when I execute this query, Sequelize seems to be treating the variable id as an object instead of substituting its actual value. As a result, the generated SQL query contains [object Object] instead of the expected value of id. Here's the output:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `user_posts_id` FROM `user_posts_boxes` AS `user_posts_boxes` WHERE `user_posts_boxes`.`user_id` = '[object Object]' LIMIT 5;
[]
```

It prints object instead of variable value and print the actual query that sequelize prepare.

The actual raw query I'm trying to replicate in Sequelize is as follows:

```
SELECT `user_posts_id` FROM `user_posts_boxes` AS `user_posts_boxes` WHERE ( `user_posts_boxes`.`user_id` = '5' OR `user_posts_boxes`.`user_id` IN (select following_id from friend WHERE friend.follower_id = user_posts_boxes.user_id and friend.status='A' and friend.following_id=5)) LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Sequelize 5. Use Symbol based operator and it should be fine https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417